# NullPointerException when editing Android Layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm just starting to learn how to develop for Android in Eclipse. I'm  going through some tutorials on developing UI, and I noticed that the error log in Eclipse keeps logging NullPointerExceptions.

Currently I have a single layout with a label, button, and text box. Whenever I interact with the WYSIWYG UI editor, such as selecting the button, the error log fills up with a bunch of these exceptions. Here's the details of one of the exceptions.

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Sat Mar 01 19:32:57 PST 2014


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.getDefaultProperties(RenderSessionImpl.java:1476)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.getDefaultProperties(BridgeRenderSession.java:68)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ViewHierarchy.getDefaultProperties(ViewHierarchy.java:710)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getStringValue(XmlProperty.java:209)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getValue(XmlProperty.java:221)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.getText(XmlPropertyEditor.java:116)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.paint(XmlPropertyEditor.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawProperty(PropertyTable.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawContent(PropertyTable.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.handlePaint(PropertyTable.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.access$200(PropertyTable.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable$3.handleEvent(PropertyTable.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PRINTCLIENT(Composite.java:1639)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4590)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.callWindowProc(Button.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Here's the code for my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StatusActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post some java code because I don't see anything wrong with your xml code.

Comment: There really isn't any Java at this point. This is a new project with a single activity created with the project that sets the layout in onCreate() and menu in onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: Actually I'm trying to learn Git at the same time so I've been pushing my work to a Github repository. Here it is: https://github.com/aireq/android-bootcamp/tree/master/Yamba

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is inside of "adt bundle". 
Can you  try import that project using other adt ?
sry, english isn't my main language =/.